# Filenames sequentially in R

Tags: r, printf, filenames

I am trying to create some files that are named sequentially using the piece of below code:

```
str1 = 'GLS-GP-'
str2 = '_Q493R'
DDMMYY = format(Sys.Date(), '%d%m%y')
Plate[is.na(Plate)] <- ""
write.table(Plate, file = paste0(str1, DDMMYY, "%-02i", str2, '.txt'), quote = FALSE, sep = "\t", dec = ".",
row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
```

I'd seen that other people had been using `sprintf()` instead of `print0()` but that didn't seem to work with the text strings I had in the rest of the file name. Basically what I want to do is have the first file on each day be like this: `str1DDMMYY-01str2.txt` and then `02` for the second file etc.

Apologies if this has been asked before but I wasn't able to find a solution that worked for me. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The only data set in the question is `Plate`, how do you know how many files you need to write?

Comment: Something like `sprintf("%s%s-%02d%s.txt", str1, DDMMYY, 1:10, str2)`? With `1:10` the sequence corresponding to the data sets to be written

Comment: I've not shown the start of the code but basically I've combined 4 csv files together into one dataset called Plate. The aim is for the code to be run with 4 different input files each time but I don't want the output file to be called the same thing each time its run. The problem is as I'm trying to automate something thats already done in the lab I need the output filename to match what is currently done i.e. GLS-GP-190222-01_Q493R

Comment: Create the filenames with the code in my comment but with `1:4`. See what it outputs. Then use those names.

Comment: `I've not shown the start of the code` you've shown neither `sprintf()` nor `print0()`.